# Dock Fill affects flood fill result

Tags: c#, drawing

I'm writing a drawing program like MS Paint. The canvas is a panel and is placed in another one so I can use scrollbars. For the fill operation I implemented flood fill algorithm. To store the drawing I create a bitmap and on paint event I draw that bitmap to the screen.

If I leave the Dock property of the canvas as is (i.e.: None), it will leave out a triangle area unfilled. If I change Dock property to Fill, the algorithm works correctly, but in this case I can't control the canvas size anymore. In both case, my fill algorithm didn't touch the canvas (it processes the bitmap I created before), how can Dock affect my fill result?

Below is the simplified code and the images generated. Each program produces two images: the bitmap **before** the fill operation and the bitmap **after** flood fill.

https://github.com/01885404983/debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out that my index calculation is wrong: instead of using `bmpData.Stride`, I use `img.Width` and hence my code accessed the image padding, which contains uninitialized data. The canvas panel just changed that data by chance. Another bug is in the order of color bytes, I use red-green blue while actually it is blue-green-red.